# How to unsplit the display

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I accidently split the display on the same screen. How do i unsplit it?
[image]

As you can see in the picture above, i have 1 LCD screen with an additional monitor. However, the LCD shows 1/2.
How do I undo this action?
I am running windows 7

Comment: All that 1/2 means is that monitor 1 and 2 are displaying the same thing. Like Ugur stated select something other than duplicate.

Comment: More information might be useful - what's your main LCD screen? What GPU? What's the *practical* issue this causes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change "multiple displays" to something other than duplicate